# Magento 2 : How to know "used_in_forms" param of eav attribute for a form?

Tags: magento2, attributes, forms, customer-attribute, eav-attributes

I was wondering if there is a full proof method for finding  all `used_in_forms` params of eav attribute which is specified in `InstallData.php` to create all kind of attributes for a form or maybe someone can list all the `used_in_forms` for all default Magento forms.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get all **used_in_forms** in magento by typing below query,

Used in form customer attribute:

> SELECT DISTINCT form_code FROM `customer_form_attribute` WHERE 1

```
    adminhtml_checkout
    adminhtml_customer
    adminhtml_customer_address
    checkout_register
    customer_account_create
    customer_account_edit
    customer_address_edit
    customer_register_address
```

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. Can you also include "used_in_forms" for product attributes in your reply?

Comment: for product attributes you can find Stores -> Product attributes

Comment: "used_in_forms" is not used for product attributes ..

Comment: something I have noticed: adminhtml_customer, adminhtml_customer_address are not displayed on the magento admin in the "Forms to Use In" when you edit an attribute